# Writing Barcode content as label below the Barcode using Java Zxing API

Tags: java, barcode, zxing, qr-code, barcode-printing

I am using zxing api for creating barcode. But while creating i am not able to write barcode content as label below the barcode.

output -- 
[image]

output required --
[image]

The code to generate these barcode are as such -

```js
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.MultiFormatWriter;
import com.google.zxing.WriterException;
import com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter;
import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;

public class BarcodeTesting {

 private static void wrtieToStream(BitMatrix bitMatrix) {
  try {
   MatrixToImageWriter.writeToStream(bitMatrix, "png", new FileOutputStream(new File("hello" + ".png")));
   System.out.println( " Barcode Generated.");
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 private BitMatrix generateBitMatrix(String content, BarcodeFormat format, int width, int height) {
  MultiFormatWriter writer = new MultiFormatWriter();
  BitMatrix bitMatrix = null;
  try {
   bitMatrix = writer.encode(content, format, width, height);
  } catch (WriterException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return bitMatrix;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  BarcodeTesting obj = new BarcodeTesting();
  BarcodeFormat barcodeFormat = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
  BitMatrix bitMatrix = obj.generateBitMatrix("MY QR Code 123", barcodeFormat, 24, 24);
  // String formatString = format.toString();
  wrtieToStream(bitMatrix);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the QRCode specifiaction does not provide an option to include the content into the image I do not think zxing or any other barcode generator does offer this functionality. You will have to add the text to the image on your own. Be aware that you have to leave enough white space around the QRCode. Your above image doesn't have enough whitespace at the bottom.

Comment: @tobltobs.I am trying to generate 5000-8000 barcode. using the itextpdf api i am able to create such kind of barcode in a pdf file, but using zxing i am still trying to find code snippet using which i can do so..

Answer (score 0):

@tobltobs. I search a lot but didn't find any way in zxing api to do as i am expecting . So as per your suggestion i created a image in which i pasted my barcode after generating & reading it.Then i write barcode content as String below that image .
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Barcode4j` can be used to embed text along with the bar code.

[This link](https://chillyfacts.com/generate-barcodes-dynamically-using-java/) has working java code.